# calling a method with a parameter to another method

Tags: java

im trying to work out how, or if its possible to call a method which has a parameter in it. i will like to use the requiredPaint method in the costForPaint method. (the code has been simplified):

```
public class job {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rooms = 1;
    double squareFeet = 0;
    double totalSquareFeet = 115;

    totalSquareFeet = squareFeet + totalSquareFeet;

    }

requiredPaint(totalSquareFeet);

//i want to use the totalSquareFeet in this method, this is why it is called
public static double requiredPaint(double totalSquareFeet) {

    double totalPaint = totalSquareFeet / 115;

    return totalPaint;

}

public static double costForPaint() {

    double paintCost = 2;

    //shows error where required paint is
    double totalPaintCost = requiredPaint() * paintCost;

    return totalPaintCost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **requiredPaint** method in **costPaint** method, then you need to mandatorily send a double parameter to requiredPaint method. 
Now that entirely depends on how you are going to implement your functionality.

You can add a parameter of type double to your costForPaint method as :

```
public static double costForPaint(double totalSquareFeet) {

    double paintCost = 2;

    //shows error where required paint is
    double totalPaintCost = requiredPaint(totalSquareFeet) * paintCost;

    return totalPaintCost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible and very common to call methods that require arguments. You are unable to call the method **requirePaint()** because you are trying to call it from an invalid place. Put the method inside the **main()** method and it should work fine. Look below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rooms = 1;
    double squareFeet = 0;
    double totalSquareFeet = 115;

    totalSquareFeet = squareFeet + totalSquareFeet;
    requiredPaint(totalSquareFeet); //here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1> In Java, if you have declared a parameter to method, then it is compulsory to pass that param (either null or some value). Here is an flow that can be done with your requirements.

2> Also you can not call a method in class block. so I removed `requiredPaint(totalSquareFeet);`

```
public class job {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rooms = 1;
        double squareFeet = 0;
        double totalSquareFeet = 115;
        totalSquareFeet = squareFeet + totalSquareFeet;
        costForPaint(totalSquareFeet);
    }

    //i want to use the totalSquareFeet in this method, this is why it is called
    public static double requiredPaint(double totalSquareFeet) {
        double totalPaint = totalSquareFeet / 115;
        return totalPaint;
    }

    public static double costForPaint(double totalSquareFeet) {

        double paintCost = 2;

        //shows error where required paint is
        double totalPaintCost = requiredPaint(totalSquareFeet) * paintCost;

        return totalPaintCost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be Like-

```
public static double costForPaint() {

     double paintCost = 2;
     double totalPaint = 15;//any number you want to initialize in totalPaint 

     double totalPaintCost = requiredPaint(totalPaint) * paintCost;

     return totalPaintCost;
}
```

You are getting error because requiredPaint() is a parameterized method and you are not giving any parameter in it.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the issues in your code.

1) You haven't followed java naming convention(Declaring class name with `CamelCase`(Job))

2) You have defined method `requiredPaint` with double parameters but you are calling it without any.

```
class job {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rooms = 1;
    double squareFeet = 0;
    double totalSquareFeet = 115;
    totalSquareFeet = squareFeet + totalSquareFeet;
    requiredPaint(totalSquareFeet);
}

//i want to use the totalSquareFeet in this method, this is why it is called
public static double requiredPaint(double totalSquareFeet) {
    double totalPaint = totalSquareFeet / 115;
    return totalPaint;
}

public static double costForPaint() {
    double paintCost = 2;
    //Passing paintCost parameter to method
    double totalPaintCost = requiredPaint(paintCost) * paintCost;
    return totalPaintCost;
 }
}
```